# Is it possible to sort HTML table with multiple rowspans?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I need to sort HTML tables using jQuery, but they have multiple rowspans and they don't have a pattern (the rowspans can be any size or be in any column). It is possible to do it?

(I've searched and haven't found any tool nor plugin that does it)

Comment: Try  Datatables

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29319/new-rowsgroup-plugin-merge-cells-vertically-rowspan